# Pandas read_csv throws ValueError while reading gzip file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a gzip file using `pandas.read_csv` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.ZIP.gz", usecols=[*range(0, 39)], encoding="latin1", skipinitialspace=True)
```

But it throws this error:

> ValueError: Passed header names mismatches usecols

However, if I manually extract the zip file from gz file, then `read_csv` if able to read the data without errors:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.ZIP", usecols=[*range(0, 39)], encoding="latin1", skipinitialspace=True)
```

Since I have to read a lot of these files I don't want to manually extract them. So, how can I fix this error?

Comment: you have two levels of compression - `gzip` and `zip` - but `pandas` know how to work with only one level of compression

Comment: you can use module `zipfile` with `io.BytesIO` to extract it to file-like object in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two levels of compression - `gzip` and `zip` - but pandas know how to work with only one level of compression.

You can use module `gzip` and `zipfile` with `io.BytesIO` to extract it to `file-like object` in memory.

---

Here minimal working code

It can be useful if `zip` has many files and you want to select which one to extract

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip
import zipfile
import io

with gzip.open('data.csv.zip.gz') as f1:
    data = f1.read()

file_like_object_1 = io.BytesIO(data)

with zipfile.ZipFile(file_like_object_1) as f2:
    #print([x.filename for x in f2.filelist])  # list all filenames
    #data = f2.read('data.csv')                # extract selected filename
    #data = f2.read(f2.filelist[0])            # extract first file
    data = f2.read(f2.filelist[0].filename)    # extract first file

file_like_object_2 = io.BytesIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(file_like_object_2)

print(df)
```

But if `zip` has only one file then you can use `read_csv` to extract it - it needs to add option `compression='zip'` because `file-like object` has no filename and `read_csv` can't use filename's extension to recognize compressed file.

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip
import io

with gzip.open('data.csv.zip.gz') as f1:
    data = f1.read()

file_like_object_1 = io.BytesIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(file_like_object_1, compression='zip')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `gzip` module to unzip all your files  somethings like this

> 

```
 for file in list_file_names:
    file_name=file.replace(".gz","")
    with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        with open(file_name,"wb") as r:
            r.write(file_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zipfile` module, such as :

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
```